# Slick way to reverse the (binary) digits of a number in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I am looking for a slick function that reverses the digits of the binary representation of a number.

If `f` were such a function I would have

`int(reversed(s),2) == f(int(s,2))` whenever s is a string of zeros and ones starting with 1.

Right now I am using `lambda x: int(''.join(reversed(bin(x)[2:])),2)`

which is ok as far as conciseness is concerned, but it seems like a pretty roundabout way of doing this.

I was wondering if there was a nicer (perhaps faster) way with bitwise operators and what not.

Comment: Why do you have the call to `list()` in there? `str.join()` will take any iterable. I also don't see this as roundabout at all - it's written almost exactly as you explain it.

Comment: @Lattyware Right, that wasn't needed. I just felt it was roundabout in the sense that I manipulate strings, when it seems really like a numeric problem. Although, suggestions on how to improve the string method is cool too.

Comment: @math4tots: It seems unlikely that any method involving bit manipulation would be faster since it would inevitably involve interpreted loops. This is, of course, in stark contrast to languages like C, where bit twiddling would be the natural way to go.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using mathematical operations that takes advantage of the two's complement representation of a number, without reversing at all?

Comment: Well, there may be something mathematically equivalent to reversing the digits in binary - but nothing jumps to mind for me. As far as I see it, this is not a numerical problem at all, you want to manipulate a sequence of items - which is exactly what you do.

Comment: Most or all of the bit-twiddling solutions that you might find are going to assume fixed-width integers. For example if you reverse the bits of the integer `1` *you* want `1` as the result, but C programmers are generally going to want either 2^15 or 2^31 according to how many bits there are in `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
int('{0:b}'.format(n)[::-1], 2)
```

or

```
int(bin(n)[:1:-1], 2)
```

---

The second method seems to be the faster of the two, however both are much faster than your current method:

```
import timeit

print timeit.timeit("int('{0:b}'.format(n)[::-1], 2)", 'n = 123456')

print timeit.timeit("int(bin(n)[:1:-1], 2)", 'n = 123456')

print timeit.timeit("int(''.join(reversed(bin(n)[2:])),2)", 'n = 123456')
```

```
1.13251614571
0.710681915283
2.23476600647
```

Comment: Does not work for negative numbers...`>>> int(bin(-128)[:1:-1], 2)`

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '00000001b'`

Comment: Also, very strange that every power of 2 has the same reverse value of `1`. `>>> int(bin(4)[:1:-1], 2) = 1`, `>>> int(bin(8)[:1:-1], 2) = 1`, `>>> int(bin(16)[:1:-1], 2) = 1`, etc. This reverse is definitely not transitive in Python.

Comment: @AndrewMao Yes because a power of two has a binary representation of the form `10000...00`, so the reverse of this is always `1`.

Comment: Of course, but it's just strange in a variable-width integer setting :)

Answer (score 8):

You could do it with shift operators like this:

```
def revbits(x):
    rev = 0
    while x:
        rev <<= 1
        rev += x & 1
        x >>= 1
    return rev
```

It doesn't seem any faster than your method, though (in fact, slightly slower for me).

Comment: Love this solution for it's simplicity and adaptability!
Assume you have range 1 to 15 and you want to invert them, you can just use `for _ in range(4)` instead of `while`, thus all integers are handled like they have length 4.
You don't have to care for padding or anything else!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion:

```
In [83]: int(''.join(bin(x)[:1:-1]), 2)
Out[83]: 9987
```

Same method, slightly simplified.

Comment: I don't really see this is better. It just uses a more obscure method of reversing it. Personally, I'd much rather see the marginally more verbose, but largely more readable version.

Comment: Even simpler without join: `int(bin(n)[:1:-1], 2)`

Answer (score 2):

I would argue your current method is perfectly fine, but you can lose the `list()` call, as `str.join()` will accept any iterable:

```
def binary_reverse(num):
    return int(''.join(reversed(bin(num)[2:])), 2)
```

It would also advise against using `lambda` for anything but the simplest of functions, where it will only be used once, and makes surrounding code clearer by being inlined.

The reason I feel this is fine as it describes what you want to do - take the binary representation of a number, reverse it, then get a number again. That makes this code very readable, and that should be a priority.

Answer (score 2):

What if you wanted to reverse the binary value based on a specific amount of bits, i.e. 1 = 2b'00000001? In this case the reverse value would be 2b'10000000 or 128 (dec) respectively 0x80 (hex).

```
def binary_reverse(num, bit_length):
    # Convert to binary and pad with 0s on the left
    bin_val = bin(num)[2:].zfill(bit_length)
    return int(''.join(reversed(bin_val)), 2)
    # Or, alternatively:
    # return int(bin_val[::-1], 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an entire half chapter of [Hacker's Delight](https://web.archive.org/web/20190915025154/http://www.hackersdelight.org/) devoted to this issue (Section 7-1: Reversing Bits and Bytes) using binary operations, bit shifts, and other goodies. Seems like [these are all possible in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) and it should be much quicker than the binary-to-string-and-reverse methods.

The book isn't available publicly but I found this blog post that discusses some of it. The method shown in the blog post follows the following quote from the book:

> Bit reversal can be done quite efficiently by interchanging adjacent
> single bits, then interchanging adjacent 2-bit fields, and so on, as
> shown below. These five assignment statements can be executed in any
> order.

[http://blog.sacaluta.com/2011/02/hackers-delight-reversing-bits.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20160506033345/http://blog.sacaluta.com/2011/02/hackers-delight-reversing-bits.html)

Comment: That makes presumptions about potential size of numbers that don't hold in Python.

Comment: Well, if you have 32-bit integers, you do 5 operations, and if you have 64-bit integers, you do 6. Not too hard...

Comment: Except Python will automatically promote numbers to infinitely large representations - [the docs state *'Integers have unlimited precision.'*](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex). You would need infinite operations.

Comment: That's silly. How do you do two's complement arithmetic if you don't have a fixed bit-length number? There is no unique reverse of a negative two's complement number if the number of bits isn't defined.

Comment: You don't. You do it a way that makes sense in a high-level language like Python.

Comment: That link also states ['Negative numbers are treated as their 2’s complement value'](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex). So what happens when you reverse a negative number?

Comment: The natural extension of 2's complement arithmetic for arbitrary size integers leads to 2-adic integers: http://jonisalonen.com/2013/infinite-integers/ (I don't know if Python uses the 2-adic representation or some other, though.)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def bit_rev(n):
...     return int(bin(n)[:1:-1], 2)
...
>>> bit_rev(2)
1
>>>bit_rev(10)
5
```