# How to reverse a binary number?

Tags: go

I'm newbie in Golan, this should be an easy question for experienced golang devs. I try to do the [same test from Spotify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180168/slick-way-to-reverse-the-binary-digits-of-a-number-in-python) to see how fast we can go in Golang :)

Comment: Don't forget the new math/bits package with the August 2017 Go 1.9 release. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45907535/6309).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual [bit-twiddling C solutions](http://blog.sacaluta.com/2011/02/hackers-delight-reversing-bits.html) translate immediately to Go.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func BitReverse32(x uint32) uint32 {
    x = (x&0x55555555)<<1 | (x&0xAAAAAAAA)>>1
    x = (x&0x33333333)<<2 | (x&0xCCCCCCCC)>>2
    x = (x&0x0F0F0F0F)<<4 | (x&0xF0F0F0F0)>>4
    x = (x&0x00FF00FF)<<8 | (x&0xFF00FF00)>>8
    return (x&0x0000FFFF)<<16 | (x&0xFFFF0000)>>16
}

func main() {
    cases := []uint32{0x1, 0x100, 0x1000, 0x1000000, 0x10000000, 0x80000000, 0x89abcdef}
    for _, c := range cases {
        fmt.Printf("%08x -> %08x\n", c, BitReverse32(c))
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose the input is a uint64. What's the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Note: since 2013, you now have a dedicate [`math/bits` package](https://golang.org/pkg/math/bits/) with [Go 1.9 (August 2017)](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#math-bits).

And it does come with  a collection of [`Reverse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/bits/#Reverse) and [ReverseBytes()](https://golang.org/pkg/math/bits/#ReverseBytes) functions: no need to implement one anymore.

Plus, on most architectures, functions in this package are additionally recognized by the compiler and treated as intrinsics for additional performance.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight-forward solution would be converting the bits into a number with [strconv](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt) and then reversing the number by shifting the bits. I'm not sure how fast it would be, but it should work.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    bits := "10100001"
    bits_number := 8
    number, _ := strconv.ParseUint(bits, 2, bits_number)
    r_number := number - number // reserve type
    for i := 0; i < bits_number; i++ {
        r_number <<= 1
        r_number |= number & 1
        number >>= 1
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s [%d]\n", strconv.FormatUint(r_number, 2), r_number)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/YLS5wkY-iv